# Power electronics/ electrical memory

Tags: analog, memory

I am designing a machine which can detect that an appliance is on standby, and carry out a function based on this. But can this be done without the use of a microcontroller? The machine will need memory to remember the state of an appliance, hence i decided to use an arduino, but is it possible to store memory without the use of a microprocessor in an analog sense?

Comment: Yes, but why would you?

Comment: Are you seriously asking if there is such a thing as memory not built into a microcontroller!!?

Comment: I am aware there is memory outside of a microcontroller, but i would like to make a circuit, which for example, will be able to remember the input current, and carry out an action if this input current drops/increases. Not sure if this can be done without a microcontroller. I am trying to avoid the use of an arduino/rasberrypi, because i have been asked to do so from my teacher

Comment: @BrianDrummond thank you for your help. Basically, i have a current sensor, which senses the input current from an appliance. I want it to remember the input as max. If the input drops below 50% of max, then the power relay shuts the circuit, hence turning off the input appliance. Can all of this work with an ADC, Decision maker and memory, without the use of a microcontroller? Thanks again for the help

Comment: Everything can be done without a micro-controller, but it is often foolish to do so. In your case: how long do you need to remember that maximum? Or can you manually set it to? (And to prevent your question from being closed for showing no effort: what have you reseached so far?)

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I have built a device, with a current sensor and arduino uno, which can detect the current, and notify the user when the current drops. But now my teacher wants me to abandon the arduino, and work solely with electrics, just from the purpose of the project.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I would like it to remember the max indefinitely, or as long as possible. the device stays runs in conjunction with an appliance, so if an appliance stays on, so does my device. but if an appliance turns to standby mode, my decivce detects it and turns it off. But I guess the memory can be refreshed every 10 mins, so it records a new max every 10 mins, so it doesnt have to rememember for too long

Answer (score 1):

Ask your teacher what he/she wants.

You can drop the arduino and use a bare micro-controller. This makes the most sense to me, and it is what a commercial product would probably do.

You could do the same thing the micro did, but in digital logic. You'd need to remember the highest value, and compare it to the current value. This can be done with a compare circuit and a register, but that feels like creating a CPU from scractch. But maybe that's what your teacher wants.

Or you could go the analog route. If your teacher is old-school, this might be his preference (or it might be all he knows about.) Comparing values is easy (comparator or op-amp), selecting the maximum is easy (one or two diodes), but remembering the max value is a challenge (capacitor with low discharge).